# Should tags centripetal-force and centrifugal-force be linked?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [centripetal-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centripetal-force) and [centrifugal-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centrifugal-force) are currently separate tags. Should they be linked?

Comment: Generally speaking, suggestions for tag synonyms should go [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451).

Answer (score 4):

I think it's fine to keep them separate, since they're different concepts.

[image: XKCD 123]

Comment: Eppur è fittizia

Comment: I think the upvotes here (including mine too, :P) are solely out of admiration for the xkcd. Qmechanic posted in the comment what was an appropriate direction. :)